# Which of the following vectors are in the span of $v_1, v_2, v_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Given the vectors $v_1 = (2,1,0,3)$, $v_2 = (3,-1,5,2)$ and $v_3=(-1,0,2,1)$, verify that the following vectors are in the span of ${v_1,v_2,v_3}$
>   a) $(0,0,0,0)$
>   b) $(1,1,1,1)$

For b) I reduced the following matrix:
$\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
2 & 3 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 5 & 2 & 1 \\
3 & 2 & 1 & 1
\end{array}
\right]$

and got

$\left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 4 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & -5 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 3 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & -1
\end{array}
\right]$

Since the last two rowse are inconsistent, the system is inconsistent. So that means that $(1,1,1,1)$ is not in the span of ${v_1,v_2,v_3}$ doesn't it?

For a) I'm thinking I don't even have to do gaussian elimination because the trivial linear combination of these vectors will result in $(0,0,0,0)$ and it will be in the span of ${v_1,v_2,v_3}$. Is that right?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasonings for a) and b) are correct.